# How to extend model on serializer level with django-rest-framework

Tags: python, django-rest-framework

My model looks like this:

```
class MenuItem(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    components = models.ManyToManyField(Component, through=MenuItemComponent)

class Component(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=500)

class MenuItemComponent(models.Model):
    menuItem = models.ForeignKey('MenuItem')
    component = models.ForeignKey(Component)
    isReplaceable = models.BooleanField()
```

What I'd like to do is expose a list of Components (NOT MenuItemComponents) in given MenuItem that would include the isReplaceable field. So far I have:

```
#views.py

class MenuItemComponentList(generics.ListAPIView):
    """
    Displays components for given MenuItem
    """
    model = MenuItemComponent
    serializer_class = MenuItemComponentSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        itemId = self.kwargs['itemId']
        return MenuItemComponent.objects.filter(menuItem__pk=itemId)



#serializers.py

class MenuItemComponentSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = MenuItemComponent
```

Which exposes a list of MenuItemComponents and forces clients to make multiple calls in order to retrieve all Components. Exposing Components list with additional data from isReplaceable field would solve the problem.

**EDIT**
In the end I'd like to get a list that lists Component elements but the elements are exteded with isReplaceable field from MenuItemComponent model:

```
{
    "count": 2, 
        "next": null, 
        "previous": null, 
        "results": [
        {
            "url": "http://localhost:8000/api/component/1/", 
            "name": "component 1", 
            "isReplaceable": true
        }, 
        {
            "url": "http://localhost:8000/api/component/2/",  
            "name": "component 2",
            "isReplaceable": false
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Could you maybe give an example of what you'd want the final representation to look like?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, create a view that will return the MenuItemComponent instances that you're interested in.

```
class ListComponents(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = MenuItemComponentSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        """
        Override .get_queryset() to filter the items returned by the list.
        """
        menuitem = self.kwargs['menuitem']
        return MenuItemComponent.objects.filter(menuItem=menuitem)
```

Then you need to create a serializer to give you the representation you want.  Your example is a bit more interesting/involved than the typical case, so it'd look something like this...

```
class MenuItemComponentSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    url = ComponentURLField(source='component')
    name = Field(source='component.name')
    isReplaceable = Field()
```

The fields 'name' and 'isReplaceable' can simply use the default read-only `Field` class.

There's no field that quite meets your 'url' case here, so we'll create a custom field for that:

```
class ComponentURLField(serializers.Field):
    def to_native(self, obj):
        """
        Return a URL, given a component instance, 'obj'.
        """

        # Something like this...
        request = self.context['request']
        return reverse('component-detail', kwargs=kwargs, request=request)
```

I think that should all be about right.

That's for a read-only serialization - if you wanted a writable serialization you'd need to look into overriding the `restore_object` method on the serializer, and using `WritableField`, or something along those lines.