# How to add custom field in ModelSerializer?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I created a `ModelSerializer` and want to add a custom field which is not part of my model.

I found a description to add extra fields [here](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#specifying-fields-explicitly) and I tried the following:

```
customField = CharField(source='my_field')
```

When I add this field and call my `validate()` function then this field is not part of the `attr` dict. `attr` contains all model fields specified except the extra fields. So I cannot access this field in my overwritten validation, can I?

When I add this field to the field list like this:

```
class Meta:
    model = Account
    fields = ('myfield1', 'myfield2', 'customField')
```

then I get an error because `customField` is not part of my model - what is correct because I want to add it just for this serializer.

Is there any way to add a custom field?

Comment: Could you expand on "But when my field is not in the model field list specified in the serializer it is not part of the validate() attr-dictionary.", I'm not sure that's very clear.

Comment: Also "it complains - correctly - that I don't have a field customField in my model.", could you be explicit about the exception your seeing - thanks! :)

Comment: I updated my post and hope it's clearer now. I just want to know how I can add a field which is not part of my model...

Comment: [How to extend model on serializer level with django-rest-framework](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13471083/how-to-extend-model-on-serializer-level-with-django-rest-framework)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django REST Framework: adding additional field to ModelSerializer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18396547/django-rest-framework-adding-additional-field-to-modelserializer)

Answer (score 67, accepted):

You're doing the right thing, except that `CharField` (and the other typed fields) are for writable fields.

In this case you just want a simple read-only field, so instead just use:

```
customField = Field(source='get_absolute_url')
```

Comment: thanks, but i want a writeable field. I pass a certain user token which identifies my user. but in my model i have the user and not the token. so i want to pass the token and "convert" it to a user object via a query.

Comment: the next thing is that source needs to target a model attribute, right? in my case i dont have an attribute to point at.

Comment: I don't understand the user/token bit of the comment.  But if you want to include a field in the serializer that gets stripped out before you restore into a model instance, you could use the `.validate()` method to remove the attribute.  See: http://django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers.html#validation  That'd do what you need, though I don't really understand the use-case, or why you want a **writable** field that's tied to a **read-only** property `get_absolute_url`?

Comment: forget about the `get_absolute_url` I just copy&paste'd it from the docs. I just want a normal writable field which I can access in the `validate()`. I just guessed that I'd need the `source` attribute...

Comment: That makes more sense. :)  The value should be getting passed through to validate, so I'd double check how you're instantiating the serializer, and if that value really is being provided.

Comment: thanks! could you maybe provide a small code sample for the case that `customField` is not in the `fields()` array but is still accessable in the `validate()` function?

Comment: Great answer, but in my case I needed to use `ReadOnlyField` instead of `Field`

Comment: If you're using a `ModeSerializer` and you want the str of a model in your api response, you can use `custom_field = serializers.CharField(source='__str__')`

Answer (score 118):

In fact there a solution without touching at all the model. You can use [`SerializerMethodField`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield) which allow you to plug any method to your serializer.

```
class FooSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    foo = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_foo(self, obj):
        return "Foo id: %i" % obj.pk
```

Comment: As OP mentioned in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14583816/django-rest-framework-how-to-add-custom-field-in-modelserializer/29475731#comment20355742_14584287), they want a writable field, which `SerializerMethodField`s are not

Comment: can you also have a `create_foo` method?

Answer (score 21):

...for clarity, if you have a Model Method defined in the following way:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    ...

    def model_method(self):
        return "some_calculated_result"
```

You can add the result of calling said method to your serializer like so:

```
class MyModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    model_method_field = serializers.CharField(source='model_method')
```

p.s. Since the custom field isn't really a field in your model, you'll usually want to make it read-only, like so:

```
class Meta:
    model = MyModel
    read_only_fields = (
        'model_method_field',
        )
```

Comment: What if I want it to be writable?

Comment: @Csaba: You'll just need to write custom save and deletion hooks for the additional content:

See "Save and deletion hooks" under "Methods" ([Here](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#methods))

You'll need to write custom `perform_create(self, serializer)`, `perform_update(self, serializer)`, `perform_destroy(self, instance)`.

Answer (score 17):

After reading all the answers here my conclusion is that it is impossible to do this cleanly. You have to play dirty and do something hadkish like creating a write_only field and then override the `validate` and `to_representation` methods. This is what worked for me:

```
class FooSerializer(ModelSerializer):

    foo = CharField(write_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Foo
        fields = ["foo", ...]

    def validate(self, data):
        foo = data.pop("foo", None)
        # Do what you want with your value
        return super().validate(data)

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        data = super().to_representation(instance)
        data["foo"] = whatever_you_want
        return data
```

Comment: If you set `write_only=True` then why do you also have `def to_representation`?    it sounds like you want both read and write....

Answer (score 14):

here answer for your question.
you should add to your model Account:

```
@property
def my_field(self):
    return None
```

now you can use:

```
customField = CharField(source='my_field')
```

source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18396622/3220916

Comment: I've used this approach when it makes sense but it's not great to add extra code to models for things that are only really used for specific API calls.

Comment: You can write a proxy model for the

Answer (score 13):

To show `self.author.full_name`, I got an error with `Field`. It worked with `ReadOnlyField`:

```
class CommentSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    author_name = ReadOnlyField(source="author.full_name")
    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = ('url', 'content', 'author_name', 'author')
```

Answer (score 11):

I was looking for a solution for adding a writable custom field to a model serializer. I found this one, which has not been covered in the answers to this question.

It seems like you do indeed need to write your own simple Serializer.

```
class PassThroughSerializer(serializers.Field):
    def to_representation(self, instance):
        # This function is for the direction: Instance -> Dict
        # If you only need this, use a ReadOnlyField, or SerializerField
        return None

    def to_internal_value(self, data):
        # This function is for the direction: Dict -> Instance
        # Here you can manipulate the data if you need to.
        return data
```

Now you can use this Serializer to add custom fields to a ModelSerializer

```
class MyModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer)
    my_custom_field = PassThroughSerializer()

    def create(self, validated_data):
        # now the key 'my_custom_field' is available in validated_data
        ...
        return instance
```

This also works, if the Model `MyModel` actually has a property called `my_custom_field` but you want to ignore its validators.

Comment: so it does not work if my_custom_field is not a property of MyModel right ? I got the error The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `MyModel` instance.

Answer (score 8):

With the last version of Django Rest Framework, you need to create a method in your model with the name of the field you want to add.

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    . . .
    def foo(self):
        return 'stuff'
    . . .

class FooSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    foo = serializers.ReadOnlyField()

    class Meta:
        model = Foo
        fields = ('foo',)
```