# Django REST Framework: adding additional field to ModelSerializer

Tags: django, rest, django-rest-framework

I want to serialize a model, but want to include an additional field that requires doing some database lookups on the model instance to be serialized:

```
class FooSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  my_field = ... # result of some database queries on the input Foo object
  class Meta:
        model = Foo
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'myfield')
```

What is the right way to do this? I see that [you can pass in extra "context"](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#including-extra-context) to the serializer, is the right answer to pass in the additional field in a context dictionary?

With that approach, the logic of getting the field I need would not be self-contained with the serializer definition, which is ideal since every serialized instance will need `my_field`. Elsewhere in the DRF serializers documentation it [says](http://django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers.html#specifying-fields-explicitly) "extra fields can correspond to any property or callable on the model". Are "extra fields" what I'm talking about?

Should I define a function in `Foo`'s model definition that returns `my_field` value, and in the serializer I hook up my_field to that callable? What does that look like?

Happy to clarify the question if necessary.

Answer (score 324, accepted):

I think `SerializerMethodField` is what you're looking for:

```
class FooSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  my_field = serializers.SerializerMethodField('is_named_bar')

  def is_named_bar(self, foo):
      return foo.name == "bar" 

  class Meta:
    model = Foo
    fields = ('id', 'name', 'my_field')
```

http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield

Comment: is it possible to add validation to such fields? my question is: how to accept custom POST values which can be validated and processes in the post_save() handler?

Comment: Note that SerializerMethodField is read-only, so this won't work for incoming POST/PUT/PATCH.

Comment: In DRF 3, it is changed to `field_name = serializers.SerializerMethodField()` and `def get_field_name(self, obj):`

Comment: whats the `foo` when def a  SerializerMethodField ? when use CreateAPIView, is the foo have stored then can use the is_named_bar() method?

Comment: So, based on this answer, if you want to pass say 12 extra fields to your serializer, you need to define 12 specific methods for each field that just returns foo.field_custom ?

Comment: "foo" here should be "instance" as it's the instance currently being 'seen' by the Serializer.

Comment: Had to change it to obj. But thanks, it was super helpful

Answer (score 58):

You can change your model method to property and use it in serializer with this approach.

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    . . .
    @property
    def my_field(self):
        return stuff
    . . .

class FooSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    my_field = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='my_field')

    class Meta:
        model = Foo
        fields = ('my_field',)
```

Edit: With recent versions of rest framework (I tried 3.3.3), you don't need to change to property. Model method will just work fine.

Comment: Thanks @Wasil! I am not familiar with the use of properties in Django models, and cannot find good explanation of what it means. Can you explain? What is the point of the @property decorator here?

Comment: it means you can call this method like a property: i.e. `variable = model_instance.my_field` gives the same result as `variable = model_instance.my_field()` without the decorator.

also: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6618176/2198571

Comment: This is not working, at least in Django 1.5.1 / djangorestframework==2.3.10. The ModelSerializer is not getting the propery even if explictly referred in "fields" Meta attribute.

Comment: you need to add the field to the serializer because it's no *real* modelfield: my_field = serializers.Field(source='my_field')

Comment: `source='my_field' ` isn't require anymore and raise an exception

Comment: This technique doesn't work anymore. `my_field` won't be included in api response. I guess you need to use `SerializerMethodField` instead.

Answer (score 19):

if you want read and write on your extra field, you can use a new custom serializer, that extends serializers.Serializer, and use it like this

```
class ExtraFieldSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    def to_representation(self, instance): 
        # this would have the same as body as in a SerializerMethodField
        return 'my logic here'

    def to_internal_value(self, data):
        # This must return a dictionary that will be used to
        # update the caller's validation data, i.e. if the result
        # produced should just be set back into the field that this
        # serializer is set to, return the following:
        return {
          self.field_name: 'Any python object made with data: %s' % data
        }

class MyModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    my_extra_field = ExtraFieldSerializer(source='*')

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ['id', 'my_extra_field']
```

i use this in related nested fields with some custom logic

Answer (score 16):

With the last version of Django Rest Framework, you need to create a method in your model with the name of the field you want to add. No need for `@property` and `source='field'` raise an error.

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    . . .
    def foo(self):
        return 'stuff'
    . . .

class FooSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    foo = serializers.ReadOnlyField()

    class Meta:
        model = Foo
        fields = ('foo',)
```

Comment: what if i want to have `request` object inside def foo(self) which could modify foo's value? (example a request.user based lookup)

Comment: What if the value of foo is coming from request?

Answer (score 12):

My response to a similar question ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14583816/django-rest-framework-how-to-add-custom-field-in-modelserializer/29475731#29475731)) might be useful.

If you have a Model Method defined in the following way:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    ...

    def model_method(self):
        return "some_calculated_result"
```

You can add the result of calling said method to your serializer like so:

```
class MyModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    model_method_field = serializers.CharField(source='model_method')
```

p.s. Since the custom field isn't really a field in your model, you'll usually want to make it read-only, like so:

```
class Meta:
    model = MyModel
    read_only_fields = (
        'model_method_field',
        )
```

Answer (score 10):

If you want to add field dynamically for each object u can use to_represention.

```
class FooSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  class Meta:
        model = Foo
        fields = ('id', 'name',)
  
  def to_representation(self, instance):
      representation = super().to_representation(instance)
      if instance.name!='': #condition
         representation['email']=instance.name+"@xyz.com"#adding key and value
         representation['currency']=instance.task.profile.currency #adding key and value some other relation field
         return representation
      return representation
```

In this way you can add key and value for each obj dynamically
hope u like it

Answer (score 5):

***This worked for me***.
If we want to just add an additional field in `ModelSerializer`, we can
do it like below, and also the field can be assigned some val after
some calculations of lookup. Or in some cases, if we want to send the
parameters in API response.

In model.py

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    """Model Foo"""
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, help_text="Customer Name")
```

In serializer.py

```
class FooSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    retrieved_time = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    
    @classmethod
    def get_retrieved_time(self, object):
        """getter method to add field retrieved_time"""
        return None

  class Meta:
        model = Foo
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'retrieved_time ')
```

Hope this could help someone.

Comment: `@classmethod` is not needed

Comment: So can you simply execute queries in your serializer?

Answer (score 3):

```
class Demo(models.Model):
    ...
    @property
    def property_name(self):
        ...
```

If you want to use the same property name:

```
class DemoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    property_name = serializers.ReadOnlyField()
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = '__all__' # or you can choose your own fields
```

If you want to use different property name, just change this:

```
new_property_name = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='property_name')
```

Answer (score 2):

Even though, this is not what author has wanted, it still can be considered useful for people here:

If you are using `.save()` ModelSerializer's method, you can pass `**kwargs` into it. By this, you can save multiple dynamic values.

i.e. `.save(**{'foo':'bar', 'lorem':'ipsum'})`

Comment: this really saved me. why is this so hard to figure out? so much of working with DRF seems so opaque. all i wanted was to upload an image and set an "uploaded_by" field with the `request.user` and that took me like days of reading documentation before finding this.

Comment: I've got your pain, the documentation for DRF is really opaque (sometimes) and almost every Django-related question on SO can go to a high school already

Answer (score 0):

As [Chemical Programer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3126753/chemical-programmer) said in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18396547/django-rest-framework-adding-additional-field-to-modelserializer#comment56106029_18426235), in latest DRF you can just do it like this:

```
class FooSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    extra_field = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_extra_field(self, foo_instance):
        return foo_instance.a + foo_instance.b

    class Meta:
        model = Foo
        fields = ('extra_field', ...)
```

[DRF docs source](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield)

Answer (score 0):

Add the following in serializer class:

```
def to_representation(self, instance):
    representation = super().to_representation(instance)
    representation['package_id'] = "custom value"
    return representation
```