# Including the get_absolute_url value in JSON output

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Just getting into Django Rest Framework.

I have a simple example running where a model is being presented through the REST API. There are no Related fields in the model, just a bunch of strings.

What is the easiest way to present the `get_absolute_url()` value of that model into the JSON output?

I'm using `serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer` in preparation for moving into more complicated models that do have related fields.

Comment: I found a lot of the answer in this [relevant post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18396547/django-rest-framework-adding-additional-field-to-modelserializer)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Approach-1 Using a `SerializerMethodField`:**

You can use a [`SerializerMethodField`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield) in your serializer to add the `get_absolute_url()` value to the serialized representation of the object.

As per the [`SerializerMethodField` docs:](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield)

> This is a read-only field. It gets its value by calling a method on
>   the serializer class it is attached to. **It can be used to add any
>   sort of data to the serialized representation of your object.**

We will define a method `get_my_abslute_url()` for the `my_absolute_url` field in our serializer which will add the absolute url of the object to the serialized representation.

```
class MyModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    my_absolute_url = serializers.SerializerMethodField() # define a SerializerMethodField        

    def get_my_absolute_url(self, obj):
        return obj.get_absolute_url() # return the absolute url of the object
```

**Approach-2 Using [`URLField`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#urlfield) with `source` argument:**

You can also use a `URLField` and pass the method `get_absolute_url` to it. This will call the method `get_absolute_url` and return that value in the serialized representation.

From DRF docs on [`source` argument:](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#core-arguments)

> The name of the attribute that will be used to populate the field. **May
>   be a method that only takes a `self argument`, such as
>   `URLField('get_absolute_url')`**, or may use dotted notation to traverse
>   attributes, such as `EmailField(source='user.email')`.

```
class MyModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    my_absolute_url = serializers.URLField(source='get_absolute_url', read_only=True)
```

**I would suggest using the 2nd approach** as DRF has explicitly used this in its docs.

Comment: How would you prepend the protocol, hostname and port to the resulting url?

Answer (score 2):

Just had to deal with this myself. Basically you'll want to leverage the [`build_absolute_uri()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.build_absolute_uri) method of the `request` available in the serializer's `context`, like so:

```py
class FooSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Foo
        fields = ("web_url",)

    web_url = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_web_url(self, obj):
        obj_url = obj.get_absolute_url()
        return self.context["request"].build_absolute_uri(obj_url)
```

Answer (score 0):

This maybe the best way in the latest version of drf instead of `URLField` way or `SerializerMethodField` way:

```py
# serializers.py
class DocumentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    url = serializers.HyperlinkedIdentityField(view_name='page-detail')  # define a SerializerMethodField
```

```py
# urls.py
router = DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'pages', xxx, basename='page') # will generate url named `page-detail` that can be reversed in `HyperlinkedIdentityField`
urlpatterns = router.urls

# Almost equal
# urlpatterns = [
#  path('page/', xxx, name='page-list'),
#   path('page/{pk}', xxx, name='page-detail'),
#]
```

After reading the source code of drf, `source=get_absolute_url` is not working now.