# DjangoRestFramework - How to create a Serializer ReadOnlyField who's value depends on the user?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Assume this is my serializer:

```
class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ('post', 'usersVoted')
        read_only_fields = ('usersVoted',)
```

`usersVoted` is a `ManyToManyField` with the User model (default Django model). What I want to do is when posts are being serialized, I also want a boolean sent to the front end which returns `True` if the current user is in the set of users in `usersVoted` (and `False` otherwise). I'm using DRF's ViewSets for my view:

```
class PostViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    A viewset that provides the standard actions.
    """
    queryset = Post.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PostSerializer
```

Is there any way for me to do this?

Comment: You can do this by creating a function that returns the boolean that you want: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18426235/1913888

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do like:

```
class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    userexists = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ('post', 'usersVoted','userexists')
        read_only_fields = ('usersVoted','userexists')

    def get_userexists(self, obj):
        if self.context['request'].user in obj.usersVoted.all():
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

Comment: `usersVoted` is already a field in my serializer (it consists of a list of User objects) which I want to be sent to the frontend, so I cannot use the name ` usersVoted = serializers.SerializerMethodField()`.