# Django Rest: Serializers Based on Multiple Querysets

Tags: django-rest-framework

I'm working with serializers as described by the link:[Serializer relations (section PrimaryKeyRelatedField)](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#primarykeyrelatedfield)

I have a slight different need, I'm sure it's really easy.

```
class Album(models.Model):
    album_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    artist = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Track(models.Model):
    album = models.ForeignKey(Album, related_name='tracks')
    order = models.IntegerField()
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    duration = models.IntegerField()

class SomeWidget(models.Model):
    album = models.ForeignKey(Album)
    track = models.ForeignKey(Track)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

My need, I need to return the following:

```
{
    'album_name': 'Things We Lost In The Fire',
    'artist': 'Low',
    'tracks': [
        '1: Sunflower',
        '2: Whitetail',
        '3: Dinosaur Act',
        ...
    ],
    'widget': [
        {
           'id': '1234',
           'name': 'my widget',
           'description': 'my description'
        }
    ]
}
```

I am trying:

```
class WidgetField(serializers.RelatedField):
    def to_representation(self, value):
        return {
            'id': '1234'
            ....
        }


class TrackListingField(serializers.RelatedField):
    def to_representation(self, value):
        ...

class AlbumSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    tracks = TrackListingField(many=True)
    widget = WidgetField()

    class Meta:
        model = Album
        fields = ('album_name', 'artist', 'tracks')
```

I keep getting the error:

```
AssertionError: Relational field must provide a `queryset` argument, override `get_queryset`, or set read_only=`True`.
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, got it. It took a little bit of Googling / trial and error. Apparently you can override the function that returns data for the field.

For example:

```
class AlbumSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    widget = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_widget(self, data):
        return {
            'id': data.id
        }
```

OR, you can do the following:

```
class WidgetSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Widget
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'description',)
```

.... and in the AlbumSerializer.get_widget function:

```
    def get_widget(self, data):
        widget = Widget.objects.get(album=data.album, track=data.track)
        return WidgetSerializer(widget, many=False, context=self.context).data
```

Finally, you don't *have* to use the function name "get_widget". You can name it whatever you want. Example:

```
class AlbumSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    widget = serializers.SerializerMethodField("fn_override")

    def fn_override(self, data):
        ....
```

You can follow the pattern in this SO question: [Django REST Framework: adding additional field to ModelSerializer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18396547/django-rest-framework-adding-additional-field-to-modelserializer)