# [DRF]: extra field in serializer with related id

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I've been trying hard but I can't find a solution for this, maybe you can help me:

I have 2 models: consumption and message.

The messages have a field "consumption" so I can know the consumption related.

Now I'm using DRF to get all the consumptions but I need all the messages related with them

This is my serializers.py file:

```
class ConsumptionSapSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    
    client = ClientSerializer(many=False, read_only=True, allow_null=True)
    call = CallSerializer(many=False, read_only=True, allow_null=True) 
    course = CourseSerializer(many=False, read_only=True, allow_null=True)
    provider = ProviderSerializer(many=False, read_only=True, allow_null=True)
    # messages = this is where I failed

    class Meta:
        model = Consumption
        fields = [
            "id",
            "client",
            "course",
            "provider",
            "user_code",
            "user_name",
            "access_date",
            "call",
            "speciality_code",
            "expedient",
            "action_number",
            "group_number",
            "start_date",
            "end_date",
            "billable",
            "added_time",
            "next_month",
            "status",
            "incidented",
            "messages"
        ]

class MessageSapSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

     user = UserSerializer(allow_null=True)

     class Meta:
         model = Message
         fields = [
            "user",
            "date",
            "content",
            "read",
            "deleted"
         ]
```

I have read here [Django REST Framework: adding additional field to ModelSerializer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18396547/django-rest-framework-adding-additional-field-to-modelserializer) that I can make a method but I don't have the consumption ID to get all the messages related.

Any clue?

Comment: What is the relationship between message and consumption? if i am not wrong message(parent) -> consumption(child)?

Comment: Yep, message has a field "consumption".

Answer (score 0):

There is `related_name` that you can set in `Message.consumption` in `models.py` in order to call `consumption.messages`.

models.py

```
class Consumption(models.Model):
   # some fields here


class Message(models.Model):
    consumption = models.ForeignKey(Consumption, ...., related_name="messages")
```

P.S. Since you didn't show your `models.py`, I am just assuming `Message.consumption` is a `ForeignKey`.

More explanation on `related_name` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2642645/13022138).