# Django rest framework: serializing extra fields that depend on other state?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18396547/django-rest-framework-adding-additional-field-to-modelserializer) asks how to add an additional field to ModelSerializer.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18426235) says you can add a `SerializerMethodField`.  But, how to implement a method field if the value of the call depends on some other parameter, like the request?

Comment: `SerializerMethodField` is a read-only field. So it is used only during serialization. You can use extra context to pass in the request to the serializer and use it there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the serializers context (see [docs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#including-extra-context)) for this

```
class MySerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    my_field = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_my_field(self, obj):
        request = self.context['request']
        # do something with request and obj
```

Then when you initialize the serializer be sure to pass in the request object in the context e.g:

```
serializer = MySerializer(myObject, context={'request': request})
```

Answer (score 0):

class MySerializer(serializers.Serializer):
my_field = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

```
def to_represention(self,instance):
       data=super().to_representation(instance)
       data["user"]="new filed"
       return data
```