# Djangorestframework, how can I use a serializer with custom fields that I want passed for the creation method?

Tags: django-rest-framework

Let's say I have the following:

```
class EntityManager(Manager):
 def create(label, entity_type, **kwargs):
    ... do stuff with label and entity type
    obj = super().create(**cleanedupkwargs)
    obj.addstuffwithlabel(label)
    return obj

class Entity(Model):
 somefields...

 objects = EntityManager()
```

There's no problem with this and I can call `Entity.objects.create(label='foo', entity_type=my_entity_type, other_params=foo)`

the issue is I'm now using a serializer and I tried this

```
class EntityBareboneSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
label = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
entity_type = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

class Meta:
    model = Entity
    fields = [
        'id',
        'label',
        'entity_type',
    ]

def validate_label(self, label):
    return label

def validate_entity_type(self, entity_type):
    return entity_type

def create(self, validated_data):
    # do stuff with label and entity type
    return Entity.objects.create(**validated_data)
```

The issue is when is_valid  is called the validated_data param comes back empty.

Any idea if it's possible to effectively use my custom create method in the serializer?

Answer (score 0):

You can pre-process the validated data, before creating an instance

```py
    def create(self, validated_data):
        label = validated_data.pop("label", "some_default_value")
        entity_type = validated_data.pop("entity_type", "some_default_value")
        obj = Entity.objects.create(**validated_data)
        obj.addstuffwithlabel(label)
        return obj
```

Comment: The issue is less the create call and moreso the required `is_valid` call.

Comment: Just to clarify the issue. this won't work as label isn't a "valid field" when the serializer tries to validate the data it'll error out before the create call is called.

Comment: In that case, why don't you add your `label` and `entity_type` to the serializer fields ? You can add any additional fields to your serializer - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18396547/django-rest-framework-adding-additional-field-to-modelserializer

Comment: Ah that does sorta work but then the when I call the is_valid method all of my input fields disappear resulting in an empty dictionary.