# xml authenticate version response via python django

Tags: python, xml, django

I have zero knowledge on XML since I really use JSON but I have a project that includes XML transactions so I have no choice
Basically, a request will sent to my API and then I will have to respond via XML like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<authenticate version="2.0">
<vendor_member_id>Unique_ID</vendor_member_id>
<status_code>0</status_code>
<message>OK</message>
</authenticate>
```

Need help please, I don't know how to achieve this..

The tricky part here is the

```
<authenticate version="2.0">
```

how will I show that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's definitely you can acheive this using Django RestFramework.

Found this `django-rest-framework-xml`

i.e)

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PARSER_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework_xml.parsers.XMLParser',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework_xml.renderers.XMLRenderer',
    ),
}
```

Comment: You can also write custom field http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14583816/django-rest-framework-how-to-add-custom-field-in-modelserializer

Comment: Is it really just that simple? Doesn't this include oauth2?

Comment: Yes that's right.  It will do. http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#django-oauth2-consumer

Comment: I actually wanna know how I will produce the <authenticate version="2.0">.. as part of the xml?

Comment: It's about your backend logic. Check user authenticated using Oauth2 then add that field. what's that tricky ?

Comment: Are you trying to tell me to just add it manually hard coded on my xml response?

Comment: yes or in other words. Just create the choice field in your curtom profile table and update that field when user try to login using which mechanism. Then add that in xml