# serializer custom queryset field

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-queryset, serialization

Is there a way to create a custom field in a serializer that calls a queryset ?
Here is what I am trying to do:

I have a serializer for Employee and I want to have "last_attendance" field included.

```
class EmployeeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Employee
        fields = ("id", 
                    "username", 
                    "first_name",
                    "last_name")
```

I would like to add one more field "last_attendance". 
Which is a queryset like this:

```
"last_attendance" = Attendance.objects.filter(employee_id = id_of_that_employee).last()
```

UPDATE:

For your info, Im trying to use EmployeeSerializer in this REST api

```
queryset = Employee.objects.annotate(fullname=Concat('first_name', Value(' '), 'last_name'))
employee_list = queryset.filter(fullname__icontains=request.POST['search_string'], 
                                company=auth_employee.employee.company.id).order_by('id') 

page = request.GET.get('page', request.POST['page'])
paginator = Paginator(employee_list, request.POST['page_limit'])

try:
    employees = paginator.page(page)
except PageNotAnInteger:
    employees = paginator.page(request.POST['page'])
except EmptyPage:
    employees = []


serializer = EmployeeSerializer(list(employees), many=True)
data = serializer.data[:]
return Response(data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

UPDATE:

I found SO that might be relevant but havent figured out how to apply [Django Rest Framework - How to add custom field in ModelSerializer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14583816/django-rest-framework-how-to-add-custom-field-in-modelserializer)

Answer (score 3):

Use [`MethodField`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield):

```py
class EmployeeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    last_attendance = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Employee
        fields = (
            "id",
            "username",
            "first_name",
            "last_name",
            "last_attendance",
        )

    def get_last_attendance(self, obj):
        attendance = Attendance.objects.filter(
            employee_id=id_of_that_employee
        ).last()
        if attendance:
            return (
                attendance.date
            )  # assuming it has this field
        else:
            return None
```

Comment: thanks. how do i get this id_of_that_employee ? is it obj.pk ?

Comment: i'ved got this error. django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Field name `last_attendance` is not valid for model `Employee`.https://gist.github.com/axilaris/5d345064d0174292f535702eed1b2276

Comment: i found this related SO https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14583816/django-rest-framework-how-to-add-custom-field-in-modelserializer. not sure if it can be applied.

Comment: i got it to work like this! https://dpaste.de/1YjT just that missing line. how do i display some fields from attendance, its only able to display one field

Comment: You need to serialize `Attendance` model data in `get_last_attendance` method.