# How to take output with return input json response in django rest framework api

Tags: json, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-serializer, django-rest-viewsets

I Want to return output with JSON response when API call with inputs in DJANGO REST FRAMEWORK,
I want **output_table_name** with DJANGO REST FRAMEWORK API response,
Can anyone please help me

**This is my models.py:-**

```
class postgis_KNN(models.Model):
    KNN_postgis_source_ZIPfile = models.FileField(upload_to='KNN_postgis/zip', blank=True, null=True)
    KNN_postgis_destination_ZIPfile = models.FileField(upload_to='KNN_postgis/zip', blank=True, null=True)
```

**This is my serializer:-**

```
class postgis_KNNSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = models.postgis_KNN
        fields = '__all__'
```

**This is **JSON** return response When API call:-**

```
GET /Georeferencing/postgis_KNN/

HTTP 200 OK
Allow: GET, POST, HEAD, OPTIONS
Content-Type: application/json
Vary: Accept

[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "KNN_postgis_source_ZIPfile": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/KNN_postgis/zip/aba.zip",
        "KNN_postgis_destination_ZIPfile": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/KNN_postgis/zip/bab.zip"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "KNN_postgis_source_ZIPfile": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/KNN_postgis/zip/abab.zip",
        "KNN_postgis_destination_ZIPfile": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/KNN_postgis/zip/baba.zip"
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "KNN_postgis_source_ZIPfile": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/KNN_postgis/zip/sourceSHAPE.zip",
        "KNN_postgis_destination_ZIPfile": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/KNN_postgis/zip/destSHAPE.zip"
    }
]
```

**But I want this return response with some output data like :-**

```
GET /Georeferencing/postgis_KNN/

HTTP 200 OK
Allow: GET, POST, HEAD, OPTIONS
Content-Type: application/json
Vary: Accept

[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "KNN_postgis_source_ZIPfile": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/KNN_postgis/zip/aba.zip",
        "KNN_postgis_destination_ZIPfile": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/KNN_postgis/zip/bab.zip"
        "Output_Table_Name": "aba_bab_join_knn"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "KNN_postgis_source_ZIPfile": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/KNN_postgis/zip/abab.zip",
        "KNN_postgis_destination_ZIPfile": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/KNN_postgis/zip/baba.zip"
        "Output_Table_Name": "abab_baba_join_knn"
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "KNN_postgis_source_ZIPfile": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/KNN_postgis/zip/source_shape.zip",
        "KNN_postgis_destination_ZIPfile": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/KNN_postgis/zip/dest_shape.zip"
        "Output_Table_Name": "source_shape_dest_shape_join_knn"
    }
]
```

Comment: are you using serializer ? share code for your seriazlier

Comment: yes i use serializer @Akashsenta

Comment: you can add custom field in your serializer like this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39489034/1079086)

Comment: not working for me @Akashsenta . i want to get my custom data output into django rest framework when api call with inputs