# Django Rest Framework ignoring custom field

Tags: django-rest-framework

I have a model with a nullable boolean field that I'd like to have serialized in a way that converts `null` in the output to `false`.

My model:

```
class UserPreferences(models.Model):
    receive_push_notifications = models.BooleanField(
        null=True, blank=True,
        help_text=("Receive push notifications))
```

I'm trying to do it with a custom field like so:

```
class StrictlyBooleanField(serializers.Field):
    def to_representation(self, value):
        # Force None to False
        return bool(value)

    def to_internal_value(self, data):
        return bool(data)


class UserPreferencesSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta(object):
        model = UserPreferences
        fields = ('receive_push_notifications',)

    receive_push_notifications = StrictlyBooleanField()
```

but this isn't working, I'm still seeing `null` in my API responses.

I think I must be missing something simple in wiring it up because I don't even get an error if I replace my `to_representation` with:

```
def to_representation(self, value):
    raise
```

DRF doesn't seem to be calling my method at all... What am I missing here?

Comment: When do you need to set `null=False`? On create, update or delete?

By the way, the function `to_representation()` I personally use to display the data in a custom way. Like, key as field and field as key...

Comment: please check this question and its answers, This will be useful to take you next step to fix. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14583816/django-rest-framework-how-to-add-custom-field-in-modelserializer

Comment: @EliasPrado it's on get. Just trying to change it in my GET response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Explanation

After looking into rest framework's `Serializer`'s `to_representation` method, you will find that it iterates through all of the fields and calls `field.get_attribute` method for each field. If the value returned from that method is `None` it skips calling `field.to_representation` entirely and set `None` as the field value.

```py
# Serializer's to_representation method
def to_representation(self, instance):
    """
    Object instance -> Dict of primitive datatypes.
    """
    ret = OrderedDict()
    fields = self._readable_fields

    for field in fields:
        try:
            attribute = field.get_attribute(instance)
        except SkipField:
            continue

        # We skip `to_representation` for `None` values so that fields do
        # not have to explicitly deal with that case.
        #
        # For related fields with `use_pk_only_optimization` we need to
        # resolve the pk value.
        check_for_none = attribute.pk if isinstance(attribute, PKOnlyObject) else attribute
        if check_for_none is None:
            ret[field.field_name] = None
        else:
            ret[field.field_name] = field.to_representation(attribute)

    return ret
```

## Solution

Override `field.get_attribute` by calling `super().get_attribute` and return `False` if the value is `None`

```py
class StrictlyBooleanField(serializers.Field):
    def get_attribute(self, instance):
        attribute = super().get_attribute(instance)
        return bool(attribute)

    def to_representation(self, value):
        return value

    def to_internal_value(self, data):
        return bool(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just write a simple function inside your serializer

```
 class UserPreferencesSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
     yourField = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)
     class Meta(object):
         model = UserPreferences
         fields = ['receive_push_notifications', 'yourField']

         def get_yourField(self, obj):
              if obj.receive_push_notifications == null:
                   return False
              else:
                   return True
```

Comment: Yeah, but I have a dozen or so such nullable boolean fields... That's a lot of boilerplate I'd like to avoid. Seems like the perfect use case for a custom field.