# Filter Child rows in a Django Queryset

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset, django-rest-framework

In a queryset I want to return a collection (by pk) and all Sales objects that have a status='ACTIVE'.

I have tried:

```
Collection.objects.filter(Sales__status="ACTIVE")
```

But I get back the collection object with all Sales objects if one of the Sales objects matches the criteria rather than just the ones that have a status of "ACTIVE"

So I have 2 models (and a reference model)

```
class Collection(models.Model):
    ID = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    collection_title = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Sales(models.Model):
    ID = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    sales_title = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class CollectionSales(models.Model):
    COLLECTIONSALES_STATUS_LIST = (
        ('ACTIVE', 'Active'),
        ('REJECT', 'Reject'),
    )
    collection = models.ForeignKey('Collection')
    sales = models.ForeignKey('Sales')
    status = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=COLLECTIONSALES_STATUS_LIST, default="ACTIVE")
    class Meta:
        db_table = "myschema_collection_sales"
        managed=False
```

EDIT:
I am trying to fit this into the Rest-Framework so that the output would be:

```
{
"count": 2, 
"next": null, 
"previous": null, 
"results": [
    {
        "ID": "1", 
        "collection_title": "My Collection 1", 
        "Sales": [
              {
                 "ID": 12,
                 "sales_title": "my sales title 12",
                 "status": "ACTIVE"
              }
         ]
    }
    ,
    {
        "ID": "2", 
        "collection_title": "My Collection 2", 
        "Sales": [
              {
                 "ID": 4,
                 "sales_title": "my sales title 4",
                 "status": "ACTIVE"
              },
              {
                 "ID": 5,
                 "sales_title": "my sales title 5",
                 "status": "ACTIVE"
              }
         ]
    }
]
}
```

Comment: I think your query was Collection.objects.filter(sales__status="ACTIVE")? It naturally returns all collections with an active sales.

Comment: What exactly do you want? Collections with an active sale? CollectionSales for an active sale?

Comment: I want the query to return the collection object along with all sales that are "ACTIVE"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to build the datastructure yourself. What you want is essentialy two queries and you cant fetch that in one call.

```
data = {"collection":None, "sales":[]}
for coll in Collection.objects.filter(sales__status="ACTIVE"):
   data["collection"] = coll
   for collsales in coll.collectionsales_set.filter(status="ACTIVE")
      data["sales"].append(collsales.collection)
```

Comment: OK, Thanks for your answer RickyA. I'll take a look and update accordingly.

Comment: The issue is I'm trying to use this with rest-framework. I've found this question but am not sure how to adapt it to my situation (if it can be adapted) : [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13471083/how-to-extend-model-on-serializer-level-with-django-rest-framework)

Comment: yes, that is a pain. I had an similar issue with tastypie. The trick was to not use the handlers that where tied to a model but to use more generic handlers that allowed you to write custom code. Maybe [this](http://django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/views.html) works for you?

Comment: Thanks RickyA, I've spent countless hours reading through the documentation but to no avail. I'm thinking I may have to restructure my models to fit the framework (which is far from ideal).

Comment: Yes, that is when I quit using these rest-frameworks and solved it with plain old django views. They are just tight to closely to the ORM...